# MATLAB error(abcdchk(a,b,c,d)); What does this mean?

Tags: matlab, octave

What does the code

```
error(abcdchk(a,b,c,d));
```

in MATLAB do? I'm trying to run a MATLAB script with this code snippet in Octave and getting

```
error: 'abcdchk' undefined near line 57 column 7
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be multiple versions of the `abcdchk()` function out there (kind of depends on where you got the code from), for example [this one from caltech](http://www.ligo-wa.caltech.edu/~cheryl.vorvick/etmx2007/OldStuffFromPCLaptop/MATLAB6p1/toolbox/matlab/polyfun/abcdchk.m) and [this one from Georgia Tech](http://www.ece.gatech.edu/research/DSP/courses/ee2200/matlab/10.signal/abcdchk.html), but they all seem to check that the dimensions of the given matrices are consistent.